# Hide DIV if empty - Plugin Gallery

Tags: plugins, php

I want to hide a gallery on a one-page website. I use **Album Gallery Plugin** which enables me to insert the gallery as a php shortcode into the sourcecode.

I would like to have the entire DIV to be removed/hidden when the gallery is empty/set as draft

Here's the SC

```
<div id="photos" class="block" style="margin-top: 50% !important;">
    <h3>photos ></h3>
        <h4>Official photos<br>
        <small>XYZ ////////////////////</small></h4>
        <p>The Band:<br>
        XYZ<br>
        Drums<br>
        XYZ</p>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[aigpl-gallery-slider id="1077" dots="false" arrows="false"]' );?>
        <h4>Live photos<br>
        <small>XYZ ////////////////////</small></h4>
        <p>XYZ live pictures</p>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[aigpl-gallery-slider id="1080" dots="false" arrows="false"]');?>
</div>
```

My website uses mostly Custom Posts and I can hide the custom post div with wp query when the content is empty. But how do I do this in combination with a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of reorganising your PHP:

```
$gallery = do_shortcode('[aigpl-gallery-slider id="1080" dots="false" arrows="false"]');

if ( ! empty( $gallery ) ) {
    echo '<div id="photos" class="block" style="margin-top: 50% !important;">'
    ...
    echo $gallery;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: ok sounds like a way forward. but I have 2x shortcodes within that div. or can I use $gallery1 and $gallery2 and wrap that code in there?

Comment: Of course. You can evaluate all shortcodes first and use logic to decide on what to show under which circumstances.